# Split the text into tokens which match the following regular expression: \w+(\.?\w+)*

Tags: regex, string, tokenize

I am trying to split the string in tokens which matches the REGEX:
`(\\w+(\\.?\\w+)*)`

for example: if the string is `abc.com wyx-ujk:wxr.c` then

token 1) `abc.com`

token 2) `wxy`

token 3) `ujk`

token 4) `wxr.c`

but unable to do it...

here is my code:

```
 String temp="abc.com wyx-ujk:wxr.c";

 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+(\\.?\\w+)*");
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(temp);
 System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach works with your test case:

```
String[] tokens = temp.split("[^\\w.]+");
```

Rather than focusing on what your target *is*, split on what it is *not*.

---

Some test code JDK7:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("abc.com wyx-ujk:wxr.c".split("[^\\w.]+")));
```

Output:

```
[abc.com, wyx, ujk, wxr.c]
```

and JDK8:

```
Arrays.stream("abc.com wyx-ujk:wxr.c".split("[^\\w.]+")).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
abc.com
wyx
ujk
wxr.c
```